# Give user permissions to htdocs in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, xampp, root

I installed xampp with root permission to opt/lampp folder in Ubuntu.but i cant access htdocs folder and unable to start apache server since the lampp folder has only root permission.How can i solve this and are there any proper way to install xampp in Ubuntu

Comment: Can you show the permission of htdocs ?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

To change ownership of htdocs folder run following command. [Replace
username with your own username]

```
sudo chown -R username:username /opt/lampp/htdocs
```

[image]

We also need to update httpd.conf file. Run following command to open
apache configuration file:
`sudo gedit /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf`

Find following lines:

```
 User nobody
 Group nogroup
```

The Complete answer with picutres is in [this article](http://www.computernetworkingnotes.com/ubuntu-12-04-tips-and-tricks/how-to-fix-permission-of-htdocs-in-ubuntu.html)

Answer (score 7):

For easy accessing htdocs directory:

```
sudo chown -R youruser:youruser /opt/lampp/htdocs
```

Also you can make changes in httpd.conf file:
    sudo gedit /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf

```
    173 User youruser
    174 Group youruser
```

Answer (score 4):

set USER Permission

```
sudo chmod 755 -R /opt/lampp/htdocs
```

Proper way to install XAMPP in ubuntu is as below.
open your terminal

[Official document](https://www.apachefriends.org/faq_linux.html)

### COMMANDS

```
1.) mkdir xampp
2.) cd xampp/
3.) wget https://www.apachefriends.org/xampp-files/5.6.20/xampp-linux-x64-5.6.20-0-installer.run
4.) chmod +x xampp-linux-x64-5.6.20-0-installer.run
5.) sudo ./xampp-linux-x64-5.6.20-0-installer.run
```

### ACCESS phpMyAdmin

```
6.) sudo vim /opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-xampp.conf
```

AND COMMENT OUT THE FOLLOWING LINE

```
Require local
```

EX.

```
#Require local
```

Save and quit the file and restart XAMPP service

```
7.) sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart
```

OVER COME THE SECURITY OPTION

```
8.) sudo /opt/lampp/lampp security
```

And follow the instruction