# Unable to navigate to /opt/lampp/htdocs in Ubuntu after granting permissions

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, lamp, gitkraken

**Problem**
I installed lampp in my fresh Ubuntu 18.04 computer. I'm using Gitkraken and i want to clone a repository inside /opt/lampp/htdocs, but Gitkraken gui shows me a permission error (Could not read the contents of opt) when i try to navigate to /opt or hardcode /opt/lampp/htdocs.

**What i have tried**
 1. First i followed the steps from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43558542/give-user-permissions-to-htdocs-in-ubuntu):
`sudo chown -R username:username /opt/lampp/htdocs`
 2. Then i tried chmod
`sudo chmod 755 -R /opt/lampp/htdocs`

**My  folder owner is correct**

```
// htdocs owner:
drwxrwxr-x 6 myusername myusername 4096 sep 20 23:27 /opt/lampp/htdocs/

// Gitkraken is in:
/snap/girkraken
```

I don't know why i can't access that folder if my user is the owner. I'm running out of ideas. Any tips?

**Thanks!**

Comment: Try _sudo_ when cloning: `cd /opt/lampp/htdocs`, Then `sudo git clone {projectUrl}`

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @amirali Yeah i can obviously do that. But the problem i'm facing is when i use "open repository" in Gitkraken gui. I mean, the gitkraken explorer can't open /opt folder and as a result i can't reach /opt/lampp/htdocs

Answer (score 5):

**Solved!**

Turns out that installing Gitkraken from "Ubuntu Software" puts it in `/snap/gitkraken` folder which has very restricted permissions.

Just download it from Gitkraken's website and do the basic permission granting for `/opt/lampp/htdocs` and you are ready to go!